# SQL query - Show main account and all secondary accounts

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I know I could get this done with some kind of loop by storing the "from Account" and "to Account" into variables or something... but I'm looking for an easier way.

The MainAccount table obviously contains 1 account number which is also stored in the AccountsInterval table. In that table, there's a range (From Account - To Account). Without looping, I'm having trouble finding a way to get all the secondary accounts for each main account. Is there an easier way?

```
CREATE TABLE #MainAccounts(id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, MainAccount NVARCHAR(20))
    INSERT INTO #MainAccounts(MainAccount) VALUES('41000')
    INSERT INTO #MainAccounts(MainAccount) VALUES('41010')
    INSERT INTO #MainAccounts(MainAccount) VALUES('41011')
    INSERT INTO #MainAccounts(MainAccount) VALUES('41999')
    INSERT INTO #MainAccounts(MainAccount) VALUES('42000')
    INSERT INTO #MainAccounts(MainAccount) VALUES('42010')
    INSERT INTO #MainAccounts(MainAccount) VALUES('42015')
    INSERT INTO #MainAccounts(MainAccount) VALUES('42020')
    INSERT INTO #MainAccounts(MainAccount) VALUES('42030')
    INSERT INTO #MainAccounts(MainAccount) VALUES('42080')
    INSERT INTO #MainAccounts(MainAccount) VALUES('42310')
    INSERT INTO #MainAccounts(MainAccount) VALUES('42999')
    INSERT INTO #MainAccounts(MainAccount) VALUES('43999')
    INSERT INTO #MainAccounts(MainAccount) VALUES('48000')
    INSERT INTO #MainAccounts(MainAccount) VALUES('48100')
    INSERT INTO #MainAccounts(MainAccount) VALUES('48199')
    INSERT INTO #MainAccounts(MainAccount) VALUES('48200')
    INSERT INTO #MainAccounts(MainAccount) VALUES('48210')
    INSERT INTO #MainAccounts(MainAccount) VALUES('48220')
    INSERT INTO #MainAccounts(MainAccount) VALUES('48299')
    INSERT INTO #MainAccounts(MainAccount) VALUES('48999')
    INSERT INTO #MainAccounts(MainAccount) VALUES('49999')

CREATE TABLE #AccountsInterval(id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, MainAccount NVARCHAR(20), FromAccount NVARCHAR(20), ToAccount NVARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #AccountsInterval(MainAccount, FromAccount, ToAccount) VALUES('41999', '41000', '41999')
INSERT INTO #AccountsInterval(MainAccount, FromAccount, ToAccount) VALUES('42999', '42000', '42999')
INSERT INTO #AccountsInterval(MainAccount, FromAccount, ToAccount) VALUES('43999', '41000', '43999')
INSERT INTO #AccountsInterval(MainAccount, FromAccount, ToAccount) VALUES('48199', '48000', '48199')
INSERT INTO #AccountsInterval(MainAccount, FromAccount, ToAccount) VALUES('48299', '48200', '48299')
INSERT INTO #AccountsInterval(MainAccount, FromAccount, ToAccount) VALUES('48999', '48000', '48999')
INSERT INTO #AccountsInterval(MainAccount, FromAccount, ToAccount) VALUES('49999', '41000', '49999')
```

If we use the example accounts; 41999, 42999, 43999... we should get the results below.

```
Main    Secondary
41999   41000
41999   41010
41999   41011
41999   41999
42999   42000
42999   42010
42999   42015
42999   42020
42999   42030
42999   42080
42999   42310
42999   42999
43999   41000
43999   41010
43999   41011
43999   41999
43999   42000
43999   42010
43999   42015
43999   42020
43999   42030
43999   42080
43999   42310
43999   42999
43999   43999
```

I've tried multiple queries, sub queries, and I'm not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ai.MainAccount as "Main", mi.MainAccount as "Secondary"
from #AccountsInterval ai
join #MainAccounts mi on mi.MainAccount >= ai.FromAccount and mi.MainAccount <= ai.ToAccount
```

...or alternatively...

```
select ai.MainAccount as "Main", mi.MainAccount as "Secondary"
from #AccountsInterval ai
cross join #MainAccounts mi
where mi.MainAccount >= ai.FromAccount and mi.MainAccount <= ai.ToAccount
```

Comment: Thanks. Long friday. Cross join. nice.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want in one query:

```
Select  M.MainAccount As Main, S.MainAccount As Secondary
From    #MainAccounts       M
Join    #AccountsInterval   I   On  M.MainAccount = I.MainAccount
Join    #MainAccounts       S   On  Convert(Int, S.MainAccount) Between Convert(Int, I.FromAccount) 
                                                                And     Convert(Int, I.ToAccount)
Order By Main, Secondary
```

---

Following your example in the question, we can limit the results to just `41999`, `42999`, and `43999`:

```
Select  M.MainAccount As Main, S.MainAccount As Secondary
From    #MainAccounts       M
Join    #AccountsInterval   I   On  M.MainAccount = I.MainAccount
Join    #MainAccounts       S   On  Convert(Int, S.MainAccount) Between Convert(Int, I.FromAccount) 
                                                                And     Convert(Int, I.ToAccount)
Where   M.MainAccount In ('41999', '42999', '43999')
Order By Main, Secondary
```

---

```
Main    Secondary
41999   41000
41999   41010
41999   41011
41999   41999
42999   42000
42999   42010
42999   42015
42999   42020
42999   42030
42999   42080
42999   42310
42999   42999
43999   41000
43999   41010
43999   41011
43999   41999
43999   42000
43999   42010
43999   42015
43999   42020
43999   42030
43999   42080
43999   42310
43999   42999
43999   43999
```